# Find application directory in electronjs

Tags: electron

I'm new in `electronjs` I want to get the path of any application for example user install application named **iMacros** I need to find the location of this software where it is install.

I checked `app.getPath()` which is not working for me because it only support few directories e.g downloads, userData etc [Documented Here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname).

Please let me know how can I find any software or application installing directory in electronJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, You could not know `any software or application installing directory`, you should get it from the app's docs, from searching for software's files, ... whatever you need to do to get the `Installed Directory`.

Because the `Installed Directory` is not fixed for all apps, they can be multiple folders, different from OS, some apps support chooses to install location(so they can be anywhere).

app.getPath() like a shortcut to some important folder(common folder) for application or OS, ex: appData or userData.

P/S: Depend on the app you want to check. On windows, you can open `Task Manager` right-click on a `running application` then `Open file location`.